# Retrieve HERE map location from Facebook event using graph api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, events

I'd like to get the latitude & longitude from HERE maps on a Facebook event.

For example this code perfectly works on the https://www.facebook.com/events/1802660966720470/ event:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=1802660966720470%3Ffields%3Dplace.fields(location)&version=v2.8

But the other https://www.facebook.com/events/664388580412878/ event does not give the coordinates:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=664388580412878%3Ffields%3Dplace.fields(location)&version=v2.8

Is it possible at all to retrieve these coordinates from FB graph api? Thanks!

Comment: No, you can only get this if the place has location data attached, which for the second event is not the case.

Comment: That's what I feared.. Thanks for the reply! :)